# Trying to rotate a guided missile in pygame

Tags: pygame, angle

Trig is not my strong suit which is why I am having probs trying to get my guided missile to rotate properly. Looks like I have the direction fine although Im still not 100% happy with the movement, so Im hoping by fixing the rotation it will fix that also. Problem is my missiles dont point towards the target (player), and they also flip at a certain point past the target. Heres is the code...the rotations just dont work correctly.

```
def update(self):
    self.calcVect()
    self.calcPos()
    self.rotate()
    self.checkBounds()
    self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

def calcVect(self):
    self.vectX = self.targetX - self.x
    self.vectY = self.targetY - self.y
    self.length = math.sqrt((self.vectX*self.vectX)+(self.vectY*self.vectY)) 
    self.normX = self.vectX/self.length
    self.normY = self.vectY/self.length
    self.dx += self.normX*self.power
    self.dy += self.normY*self.power

def calcPos(self):
    self.x += self.dx*0.2
    self.y += self.dy*0.2

def rotate(self):
    radians = math.atan2(-self.vectY,self.vectX)
    radians %= 2*math.pi
    self.dir = math.degrees(radians)
    print self.dir
    oldCenter = self.rect.center
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.imageMissile, self.dir)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = oldCenter
```

**Working Code**
Here is the new working code for the entire class. The expression at the end of this line enabled correct rotations "radians = math.atan2(self.vectX, self.vectY)- math.pi/2" even though the image was horizontal to start with.

```
class GuidedMissile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, source):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.screen = source.screen

    self.imageMissile = pygame.image.load("Images/missile.tga").convert()
    self.imageMissile.set_colorkey((0,0,255))
    self.image = self.imageMissile
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = source.rect.midbottom

    self.rect.inflate_ip(-15, -5)        

    self.x, self.y = self.rect.center
    self.X, self.Y = self.rect.center
    self.dx = 0
    self.dy = 0
    self.power = 3
    self.dir = 0

def update(self):
    self.player = goodSpritesOneGRP.sprite
    self.targetX, self.targetY = self.player.rect.center
    NX, NY = self.calcVect()
    self.calcVel(NX, NY)
    self.calcPos()
    self.rotate()
    self.checkBounds()
    self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

def calcVect(self):
    self.vectX = self.targetX - self.x
    self.vectY = self.targetY - self.y
    self.length = math.sqrt((self.vectX*self.vectX)+(self.vectY*self.vectY)) 
    if self.length == 0:
        self.normX = 0
        self.normY = 1
    else:
        self.normX = self.vectX/self.length
        self.normY = self.vectY/self.length
    return (self.normX, self.normY)

def calcVel(self,NX,NY ):
    self.dx += NX*self.power
    self.dy += NY*self.power            

def calcPos(self):
    self.x += self.dx*0.05
    self.y += self.dy*0.05

def rotate(self):
    radians = math.atan2(self.vectX, self.vectY)- math.pi/2
    radians %= 2*math.pi
    self.dir = math.degrees(radians)
    oldCenter = self.rect.center
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.imageMissile, self.dir)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = oldCenter

def checkBounds(self):
    global guidedMissile
    screen = self.screen
    if self.x > screen.get_width():
        self.kill()
        guidedMissile -= 1
    if self.x < -100:
        self.kill()            
        guidedMissile -= 1
    if self.y > screen.get_height() + 100:
        self.kill()
        guidedMissile -= 1
    if self.y < -100:
        self.kill()            
        guidedMissile -= 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `calcPos()` you have to recalculate `self.vectX` and `self.vectY`, otherwise the missile will not point to the target. And don't forget to check if `self.length == 0`

You can fix splitting `calcVect()`:

```
def calcVect(self):
    self.vectX = self.targetX - self.x
    self.vectY = self.targetY - self.y
    self.length = math.sqrt((self.vectX*self.vectX)+(self.vectY*self.vectY)) 
    if self.length != 0:
        normX = vectX/self.length
        normY = vectY/self.length

# Update velocity
def calcVel(self):
    self.dx += self.normX*self.power
    self.dy += self.normY*self.power
```

Then

```
def update(self):
    self.calcVect()
    self.calcVel()
    self.calcPos()
    self.calcVect()
    self.rotate()
    self.checkBounds()
    self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
```

This solution works, but I suggest you to write a generic method `calcVectTo(self, target)` that returns the unitary vector pointing to `(target.x, target.y)`:

```
def calcVect(self, target):
    vectX = target.x - self.x
    vectY = target.y - self.y
    length = math.sqrt((vectX*vectX)+(vectY*vectY)) 
    if length == 0:
        normX = 0
        normY = 1
    else
        normX = vectX/length
        normY = vectY/length
    return (normX, normY)
```

---

### Edit

I did not understand that the target is fixed, now it is much easier: you only need to calculate vect at the construction of the class, moving `calcVect` from `update` to `__construct` (ignore my second implementation of calcVect):

```
class GuidedMissile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, source, target):
    ...
    self.calcVect()

def update(self):
    self.calcVel()
    self.calcPos()
    self.rotate()
    self.checkBounds()
    self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: Okay it appears the problem still persists. I have included the whole class with your ammendments in case the problem lies elsewhere in the orignal post. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think the problem is how the missile is oriented in the image. If it points up then the code is `radians = math.atan2(-self.vectY,self.vectX) - math.pi/2` because the image is already rotated by 90 degrees. The "flip" is correct, you have to check the collision with the target and do something (stop rotating, exploding, ...). Also, do not mix the two implementations of `calcVect`: choose one, otherwise it is confusing how the vector is returned.

Comment: The missile points down positive x as it is brought into pygame, I have flipped it to point negative x because that is the direction of fire but with the above code it either points up or down and flips as it passes the target. It doesnt matter if I comment the flip method out because the missile just points down instead of up. Re calcVect I have 2 implementations because you have 2 also, is this a mistake or maybe I have misunderstood you. Thanks

Comment: its getting better now. I discovered that I was passing targets position through the init method of missile. That meant the targets position was only updated on creation and I had a whole lot of missiles moving around aimlessly. Still somethig is not working as it should but getting closer.

Comment: Yes, I wrote two different implementations in one answer, I could be more clear :)

Comment: Oh, it changes a lot... I'm sorry, but you should be more specific

Comment: Yes I was afraid I might be missing some important info but its hard to know what to include in code that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: OKay the rotations are working now thanks to your little bit of code "math.atan2(-self.vectY,self.vectX) - math.pi/2" Im not sure why this has oriented the missile correctly but it has. I also deleted the flip method. Thanks man, now I need to work on the accelleration as it is slow to turn around and accellerate back towards the target. Final code has been included in original post.